# Active Directory User Accounts not loading environment variables from /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc

Tags: linux, active-directory, entra-id, sssd, rocky-linux

I have Rocky Linux 8.6 server that is joined to Active Directory and I can login to it with AD accounts. I have also mounted a NFS drive to the server. The home directories for AD accounts have been specified at the mount with the below variable in the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file.

```
fallback_homedir = /mnt/nfs/home/%u
```

Now the issue is all the system users can easily load environment variables and configurations from /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc but AD users are not able to. I have looked at all the possible variables in sssd.conf but none seem to be providing a solution for it. How can I make it work for AD users. Please let me know,

I'm not sure what other info I need to provide so let me know if you need further info.

Thanks,

Comment: What shell are your AD users getting assigned? Are you using something like `default_shell = ` and/or `override_shell =` and set something custom ? _-_ Typical problems with RHEL derived distributions are remain things  denied by SELinux. Check for those. Setting the `use_nfs_home_dirs` SELiunx boolean for example might be required for starters.

Comment: @diya I'm using `default_shell` but I've specified the default path for bash to it. Not sure how this could be a problem. I have not set `skel_dir` parameter in sssd.conf which has the default value of `/etc/skel/` and is supposed to populate the user home directories from files in the specified path. I can see the `.bash*` file placed at `/etc/skel/` but they are not being added to home directories. Apparently `skel_dir` gets used only when users are created with sss_useradd command, but my users are created in AD. Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf